# Make an accumulative function on an User Item Matrix list based on a time window

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recommendation-engine

I've got a `DataFrame` representing a User-Item Matrix as a list with the columns:

```
user_id  item_id  rating  timestamp
```

As I want to make a time-aware recommender, I want to add a column with an ordered list (as I have a timestamp) of the last items rated with a `1` (for example) of the user, so I get a `DataFrame` like:

```
user_id  item_id  rating  timestamp  prev_items_rated_by_usr_with_1
```

I'm unable of making it parallely and I need it like that as the dataset is huge.

This works, but I'm not sure if it returns the items ordered by the timestamp and it is incredibly long to execute:

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row:list(df.loc[df.user_id==row['user_id']].loc[df.timestamp<row['timestamp']].loc[df.rating==1].item_id.unique()), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get previous rows data using numpy shift method. We need to import both pandas and numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

We can set index so we will sort faster it by every user and timestamp:

```
df = df.set_index(['user_id', 'timestamp'], drop=False).sort_index()
```

Then we can calculate new column by checking is previous user the same and previous score is 1:

```
df['prev_items_rated_by_usr_with_1'] = np.where(df['user_id'] == df['user_id'].shift() &
                                                df['rating'].shift() == 1, True, False)
```

Comment: Running that returns this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool'

Comment: Although it's a very good approximation to the result I'm looking for, I need the resulting list to be filled with the identifiers of the item column that satisfy the condition you've exposed. I think that's where the new error comes from, since changing the "&" for an "and" has returned the error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Hi I was testing it on sample dataset which O created. Just share few rows from your dataframe and your code to create it. I have such a errors quite often so for sure it can be fixed.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to share the data. Maybe it's due to the types of the columns and I can share it: timestamp (int64), rating(int64), user_id(int64), item_id(int64)